# Trying to set up domain and subdomain in the same port. (NGINX)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http, nginx

I am trying to run a domain and sub-domain in the same port using Nginx, and do not have success yet.

I have a domain named `www.just4bettors.mobi` which is for a mobile page, and the subdomain must be named `www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi` which is clearly for the desktop site.

If you enter `www.just4bettors.mobi` everything works, you reach the page, but if you enter `www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi` you get `This web page is not available`. This is the server block I have so far

```
server {
        large_client_header_buffers 1 1K;

        listen       80;
        server_name  ~^(?<subdomain>[^.]*)\.?just4bettors.mobi$ just4bettors.mobi;
        root   /home/c0pt/capilleira/capilleiraclickandgamblemobile/www;

        location / {
            if ($subdomain) {
               root /home/c0pt/capilleira/capilleiraclickandgambleweb/dist;
            }
            if ($host = "just4bettors.mobi") {
                root /home/c0pt/capilleira/capilleiraclickandgamblemobile/www;
            }
            index  index.html index.htm;
            ...
        }
}
```

once I try to access to `desktop.just4bettors.mobi`, the console returns this `GET http://desktop.just4bettors.mobi/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

you have that the roots are different here, mobile and web lives in separate places.

so, what am I missing here ?

Comment: I think you have a good answer below from @DonovanHernandez but I would suggest you think strongly about using separate subdmoains for mobile vs. desktop experiences.  This is really an older approach to handling the desktop vs. mobile problem.  Search engines like Google have in fact started to punish sites that do this in their search rankings, preferring a more responsive/adaptive approach.  Something to be aware of before you get too far into your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed Nginx configurations where millions of different domains were in use. It's very complicated trying to work inside one `server{}` block directive. Here is what I would do:

```
server {
    large_client_header_buffers 1 1K;
    listen 80;

    server_name www.just4bettors.mobi;
    root /home/c0pt/capilleira/capilleiraclickandgamblemobile/www;

    location / {
        ...
    }
}

server {
    large_client_header_buffers 1 1K;
    listen 80;

    server_name www.desktop.just4bettors.mob;
    root /home/c0pt/capilleira/capilleiraclickandgambleweb/dist;

    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can read more about this here: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Server_Name